# Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, passenger

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I am getting this error when trying to run [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) using Phusion Passenger under RVM on OSX Lion.

I have "redmine" and "global" RVM gemsets under Ruby 1.9.3. the "global" gemset contains the Passenger gem, other redmine specific gems are in the "redmine" gem set.

There are a lot of similar posts on stack overflow that deal with this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490119/could-not-find-i18n-0-6-0-in-any-of-the-sources),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676890/passenger-says-bundlergemnotfound-error-while-the-bundle-install-says-its-ther),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390604/phusion-passenger-is-throwing-errors-after-upgrading-ruby-and-rails-using-rvm)), all with accepted answers, however I don't believe any of them are the "correct" solution.

How can I overcome this error while having Passenger installed in my global gemset please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the first mentioned post there is most important part to use wrappers:

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p125/ruby
```

the wrappers sets up proper environment for default ruby, for using gemsets follow rvm integration instructions: https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/

Comment: This just bit me too, I don't know if other docs were off, but I was pointed at the ruby and not the wrapper.